# Which VGA to use for accelerated playback?

Tags: windows-7, intel-graphics, hardware-acceleration, ati-mobility-radeon

I've got 2 VGAs in my laptop. (The question would be too localised, but people often have an Intel integrated card and a similar discrete card. So my guess would be that the question will help others who seek the same answer.)

- Intel MHD4500
- ATI HD3650 M

Intel is said to support ALL kind of media files ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_X4500)), and ATI is known to have "[UVD+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Video_Decoder)".
Basically I'm thinking about switching to CoreAVC.

But which card should I use? ATI or Intel?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Play HD / XviD movies ? :) Guess only HD is possible with the current VGA I've got, but I want "smoother" playback there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I found out, (suprisingly) Intel got a better support for DXVA. If you install a new ffdshow codec pack for your MPC-HC for example, you'll be able to decode your HD movies with DXVA.

Answer (score 1):

To save battery power with you laptop, I would recommend the Intel VGA, if everything runs fine with the Intel, you should always use it. If you face any problems with it (videos not playing smooth or something like that), then you should change to the ATI. The video file formats which can be played do not depend on your hardware, only the capability of using hardware acceleration does.
In a nutshell you could say: Use the intel VGA (for powersaving) unless you face problems with it. There is a bit trial and error involved here.